# Congruence Relation with exponents and variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, relations

I am currently trying to solve a congruence relation with a constant and a variable, both of which have attached exponents. The relation is as follows:

$7^{95}\equiv x^{3} (mod 10)$

How does one go about solving for x when it has an attached exponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $3^3\equiv 7\pmod{10}$, so $7^{95}\equiv 3^{3\cdot95}\pmod{10}$.

Or you could observe that $7^2\equiv-1\pmod{10}$, so $7^4\equiv1\pmod{10}$, and easily reduce $7^{95}$ to its residue mod $10$, and then if necessary solve for the cube root by trial and error: there are only ten numbers to try, after all!

Comment: Awesome! That should get me started in the right direction!

Comment: The problem was really simple once I saw the relationship between the two. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Ampage: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ 2,5\nmid x,\:$ so $\rm\: mod\ 10\!:\ x^4\equiv 1\:\Rightarrow\: \color{#c00}{x^{-1}}\!\equiv x^3\!\equiv 7^{95}\!\equiv  7^{\large\, -1+4\,(24)}\!\equiv \color{#c00}{7^{-1}}\Rightarrow\:x\equiv 7$

Answer (score 1):

$7^2\equiv-1\pmod{10}, 7^4\equiv1$

So, $7$ is a primitive root $\pmod{10}$

Taking [discrete logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) on $7^{95}\equiv x^3\pmod {10}$ wit base $7$

$$95\cdot ind_77\equiv 3\cdot ind_7x\pmod 4\text{ as }\phi(10)=4$$
$$\implies 3\equiv 3\cdot ind_7x\pmod 4$$ 
$$\implies ind_7x\equiv1\pmod 4\text{ as }(3,4)=1$$
$$\implies x\equiv7^1\pmod{10}$$